# Report how many times condition is met in SAS

Tags: sas

Given a data step like this:

```
data tmp;
 do i=1 to 10;
  if 3<i<7 then do;
    some stuff;
  end;
 end;
run;
```

I want to write to the log how many times the if statement is true. For example, in this example, I want to have a line in the log that says:

> If statement true 3 times

because the condition is true when `i` is 4, 5, or 6. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `retain` to keep a counter variable, it's pretty easy to increment a count of how many times an `if` condition was met.

```
data tmp;
 retain Counter 0;
 do i=1 to 10;
  if 3<i<7 then do;
    Counter+1;
    *some stuff;
  end;
 end;
 put 'If statement true ' Counter 'time(s).';
run;
```

Note that this writes to the log once because it is the last thing that occurs before the data step terminates (there's only one loop in the data step in the example). If you wanted to do this for a data step that has more than one loop (e.g. when there is a `set` statement reading data in from another dataset, you'd want to tell SAS you only want it to report at the end of the step. You'd do it like this:

```
* create an example input data set;
data exampleData;
  do i=1 to 10;
   output;
  end;
run;

* use a variable 'eof' to indicate the end of the input dataset;
data new;
 set exampleData end=eof;
 retain Counter 0;
 if 3<i<7 then do;
  Counter+1;
  *some stuff;
 end;
 if eof then put 'If statement true ' Counter 'time(s).';
run;
```